# Lookup Dictionary Keys into a List

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary

I have two classes, one contains a dictionary, with key and value of `<string, object>` and another class that has a list that will lookup to the key (`string`) of the dictionary in another class.

```
class MyClassA
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> DictA { get; set; }
}

class MyClassB
{
    // ListB will contains all the keys in DictA
    public List<string> ListB { get; set; }
}
```

What should I do to parse the keys of DictA to ListB and whenever there is changes on DictA?

Comment: You should provide more context. Until now you have just shown the collections and not where you use/modify them. You know where the dictionary will be modified, there you need an instance of `MyClassB` to update the list

Answer (score 2):

The question is very vague, but i would suggest implementing sort of observer pattern (`MyClassB` will be observing `MyClassA`):

```
class MyClassA
{
    public delegate void DictChanged(string key, object value);
    public event DictChanged ItemAddedToDict;
    public event DictChanged ItemRemovedFromDict;
    private Dictionary<string, object> DictA { get; } = new();

    public void AddToDict(string key, object value)
    {
        DictA.Add(key, value);
        ItemAddedToDict(key, value);
    }
    
    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        var value = DictA[key];
        DictA.Remove(key);
        ItemRemovedFromDict(key, value);
    }
}

class MyClassB
{
    public MyClassB(MyClassA a)
    {
        a.ItemAddedToDict += (k, v) => ListB.Add(k);
        a.ItemRemovedFromDict += (k, v) => ListB.Remove(k);
    }
    // ListB will contains all the keys in DictA
    public List<string> ListB { get; } = new();
}
```

Then the usage would be:

```
var a = new MyClassA();
var b = new MyClassB(a);

a.AddToDict("test 1", new());

// now b.ListB contains one item "test 1"

a.Remove("test 1");

// now b.ListB is empty again
```

But remember to add all needed error handling and further refactor the code if necessary.

### Shorter solution

To simply synchronize at some point list with keys of a dict, you could also use such code:

```
a.DictA.Keys.ToList();
```

This would return list of string containing all keys from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

For keeping ListB in MyClassB updated with the keys from DictA in MyClassA you can create a method in MyClassB that takes an instance of MyClassA as an argument and updates ListB.

```
class MyClassB
{
    public List<string> ListB { get; set; }

    public void UpdateListB(MyClassA myClassA)
    {
        ListB = myClassA.DictA.Keys.ToList();
    }
}
```

You can call this method whenever DictA changes to update ListB.

You can also use an event-driven design which is rather complicated than the first approach, where MyClassA raises an event whenever DictA changes, and MyClassB subscribes to this event and updates ListB accordingly.

Comment: I think I have included all this info in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can define a composition or aggregation relationship between class A and B and whenever a key value pair is added to DictA you can add the key to ListB.